# EMI filtering on multi-FFC assembly

Tags: emc, ffc, fpc, filtering

an aspiring electronics engineer here. I do some electronics design for work and I'd like to know the following:

If I have an assembly of a main board, to which an FFC cable connects into a second board (A), to which another FFC cable connects to a last board.
[image: Board/FFC assembly]
Some signals flow back and forth between these different boards (e.g. I2C), so I'd like to do some low-pass filtering for EMI.
From my work I've learned you can put a filter in series close to the connector where the signal 'leaves' one board.
Since my signal leaves my Main board, but also board A, does this mean I should put something like a T-filter in the signals in both the Main board and in board A? Or would the two filters -separated by some FFC length and PCB- still function as one filter anyway?

I've also understood you should put a T-filter on signals that are bidirectional like the I2C SDA line, which can be pulled high and low by both the MCU and the chips on board A or B. Like so:
[image: Bidirectional]

And you should put a half T-filter on signals that are unidirectional (can only be dictated by the MCU) like the I2C SCL line:
[image: Directional]

How do I design for EMC here?

Comment: I stopped reading at FFC - didn't know what it meant.

Comment: An FFC is a Flat Flexible Cable: https://nl.farnell.com/productimages/standard/en_GB/2520212-40.jpg

Comment: What EMI issues are you hoping to fix?

Comment: Radiated emissions due to ringing of high frequency signals. The signals would be offloaded unto an FFC from the Main board, go back onto board A, then offloaded again from board A, to arrive on board B. Some signals would go the other way around: from board B to board A to Main board, or from board A to Main board.
(I just use I2C as an example in my drawing)

Comment: Why are those high frequency signals ringing? I ask because, the best way to cure EMI radiated is at source so, what causes them to ring?

Comment: They aren't ringing per se, I'm just trying to make a robust design in terms of EMC. I've understood that signals that go through connectors onto FFCs and back onto connectors are sources of EMI

Comment: A robust design (from the outset) would be **not to** use I2C across a cable but use a balanced transmission instead. However, if you have already designed it using I2C then, without understanding the EMI produced it's a fool's game to make a guess.

Comment: I2C was never intended to go off baord when Philips designed it... It also is an EMC nightmare depending on the length of line and speed.

Comment: @MadHatter what makes you say I2C is an EMC nightmare? Any real-world experiences? I've seen a product go through EMC certification easily with I2C being shared across different PCBAs through FFCs...

Comment: It is very challenging to filter because you cannot add capacitance the way you are showing with your T filter. I2C requires a relatively low capacitance bus. as many people have pointed out you're much better with a differential signal that effectively cancels out most of the radiant energy. A differential signal will also be much less noise prone. I2C was originally developed for short chip-to-chip connections on a single board. Never with the intention of leaving a board on a cable.

Comment: I have never seen a product with actual EMC testing that uses I2C how you are describing. Maybe at a low speed it is possible, but 99% of the time it is probably not the right tool. Just because you can make it work does not mean you should.